# Breadcrumb Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou montando um site e colocando o breadcrumb direto no código, só que não estou conseguindo pegar o item mãe do menu dropdown, está ficando assim o código... como posso posso puxar o item mãe?

```
  <section class="continer-fluid indice">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li>Página Inicial</li>
                <li>item mãe</li>
                <li class="active"><?php the_title(); ?>&nbsp;<?php the_subtitle(); ?></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: O item mae/pai é uma pagina? Tipo isso é uma hierarquia com pagina mae/filha ou é outra coisa?

Comment: consegui resolver com o Breacrumb do Yoast, defini na página qual era a página mãe e depois só ajustei o layout com CSS